# MVC routing vs. partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a request controller that is getting out of hand, and I want to divide the actions on several controllers while maintaining a clean URL. I'm trying to experiment with routing, but without success. I've read some examples and tutorials on routing, but, though I understand the examples, nothing seems to apply to my case, and I feel non the wiser. What I want is for the URL `Requests/Approval` to be handled on my ApprovalController instead of my RequestController, so I wrote the following.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Approval",
            "Request/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Approval", action="Index", id = "" }
        );

    }
```

But it's not working. Why? I have a folder in the my Views called Approval, and in there I have a file called `Index.cshtml`. How should I code the MapRoute?

**Edit**

I added all the routes I've got

Comment: Can you show the order in which you are mapping the other routes? It could be that another route is matching the same request.

Comment: I only have the standard "out of the box" route, otherwise. I updated the question so you can see the `RegisterRoutes` function.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind on routing is that the routes are evaluated in order and as soon as a route matches that is the one used so having default first causes it to not look any further.  You can specify the route by name which in this case is "Approval"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to swap the two MapRoute statements, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Approval",
    "Request/Approval/{action}",
    new { controller = "Approval", action="Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

The reason it is currently not working is because the first statement ('Default' route name) is getting matched before the second one is even evaluated.

In addition (as noted in my above example,) you need to remove '{controller}' in the Approval route and replace with 'Approval'... unless you specifically want the URL /Request/{ANY controller}/{action} to go through, which I doubt.  From your question it seems you only want /Request/Approval/ to go to your Approval controller.

Don't forget to keep the Default route at the bottom, so as to match your other controllers and actions.  It serves as a catch-all should no other matches exist.

Comment: That did the trick. I assume it's because I have the same number of parameters in both URLs, but how come it doesn't keep looking for alternate routes before I get told the file doesn't exist?

Comment: Becareful with this.  Now, if you try to call an action on the RequestController, MVC will look for a controller with the same name as the action.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman You are right, I just posted my edit warning about this

Comment: Thanks, I feel a little bit wiser now.

Answer (score 1):

The order you map your routes matters.  Move the second route before the default route.

You will still have a problem though, as any thing `/request/something` will look for the `SomethingContoller`.  To fix this, change your route to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Approval",
        "Request/Approval/{action}",
        new { controller = "Approval", action="Index", id = "" }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This was actually my first approach, but it didn't work. I tried @joshuam suggestion, and that did the trick.